# Class arguments inside Constructor arguments of another Class in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Could someone please help me with this one? It might sound simple but I'm having a hard time.

```
class Base { 
    int x;
    int y;

public:    
    Base(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}

};

class Derived : public Base {
    Base a;
    Base b;
    Base c;
    std::string name;

public:
    Derived(Base a_, Base b_, Base c_, std::string name_): a(a_), b(b_), c(c_), name(name_) {}
};
```

Here's the problem. I can't seem to be able to initialize this, I've tried several ways and searched the web yet I can't find a correct answer for this.

```
int main() {
    Derived var1({1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, "TEST");
}
```

Comment: You should not inherit class2 from class1, if the only thing you want in class2 is 3 class1 members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class1` constructor takes two parameters:

```
class1(int a, int b)
```

`class2` inherits from `class1`, however `class2`'s constructor fails to pass the two required parameters to its superclass.

Comment: So what's the solution here? Because I have an exercise that makes me initialize this and I can't make the private members public. I just can't figure how to declare this.

Comment: Either pass the correct arguments to the superclass, or don't have `class2` inherit from `class1`. There are no other options. This is how C++ works.

Comment: This might sound dumb, but how in this example can pass the right arguments to its superclass? I've been around this for hours.

Comment: I'm always getting an error telling me that I don't have a default constructor in class2 for class1.

Comment: This is correct. This you are not explicitly constructing the superclass, since `class1` does not have a default constructor you are getting this error. Your C++ book explains how to construct superclasses in much greater detail that can possibly be explained in a few hundred characters in a comment on stackoverflow.com. I'm sure you will be able to find more information in your C++ book.